# Rating script limit votes by ip

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to limit how many times a ip can vote the images in the database, but I do have problems

Overview of my two tables

T1 (rating)

```
id          votes       rating      category     rating
----------- ---------- ----------- ----------- -----------
```

T2 (rating_users)

```
user_id     user_ip     user_vote  user_source
----------- ---------- ----------- -----------
```

Table 1 -> id
has a relation to 
Table 2 -> user_source

I have tried so many different queries the past two days but I just can't figure out how to do this :(

Right now i use this query:

```
select *
from rating
left join rating_users on rating_users.user_source = rating.id
where rating_users.user_ip is null
    or rating_users.user_ip != $ip
order by RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Lets assume that table1 have 5 rows of data..

if ip1 enters the website and table 2 is empty (truncatet), and he votes all 5 images then the "6th" image will be nothing which is exactly what i want...

But if ip2 enters and table 2 still has the votes from ip1 then ip2 can literally vote as much as he wants because none of the rows are "NULL"...

I am really lost here i have tried to solve this since saturday/sunday night..

Can someone please help me i am getting alot of grey hair here :(

EDIT my code ->

Forside.php (index.php)

```
<?php
$dbCon = dbCon();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM rating ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = $dbCon->query($sql);
$result = $result->fetch_object();

$id = $result->id;

//$tal = ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
//$tal = long2ip($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$ip = ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

// CHECKKER OM DEN IP HAR VOTET DETTE BILLEDE
$sql = "SELECT user_ip, user_source, user_vote FROM rating_users WHERE user_ip = $ip AND user_source = $id";
$result = $dbCon->query($sql);
$result = $result->fetch_object();
$rating = $result->user_vote;


if (!empty($result)) {
//    echo 'Du har allerede votet dette billede : ' . $rating . "/5";
    //IMGINFO
    $string = "<div class=\"flex absolute centerAm borc1 boxsb\">";
    $string = $string .= "<div id=\"innerVotingWrapper\" class=\"innerVotingWrapper relative flex \">";

    $string = $string .= "<div id=\"imgInfo\" class=\"imgInfo absolute top0 right0\">";
    $string = $string .= "<div id=\"imgRefresh\">";
    $string = $string .= "</div>";
    $string = $string .= "</div>";

    $string = $string .= "<div class=\"imageWrapper mauto relative fadeInClass\">";
    $string = $string .= "<img id=\"imgSrc\" src=\"assets/img/$id.png\" class=\"babeImg borb2 boxsb\">";
    $string = $string .= "<div id=\"starWrapper\" class=\"flex absolute left0 bot0 mar10\">";

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $rating; $i++) {
        $string = $string .= "<div class='voteFull'></div>";
    }
    for ($i = $rating; $i < 5; $i++) {
        $string = $string .= "<div class='voteEmpty'></div>";
    }
    $string = $string .= "</div>"; //STAR WRAPPER
    $string = $string .= "</div>"; //IMAGE WRAPPER
    $string = $string .= "</div>";//INNER WRAPPER
    $string = $string .= "</div>";//YDRE WRAPPER

//HVIS PERSONEN IKKE HAR STEMT FØR
} else {


    $string = "<div class=\"flex absolute centerAm borc1 boxsb\">";
    $string = $string .= "<div id=\"innerVotingWrapper\" class=\"innerVotingWrapper relative flex \">";
    //IMGINFO
    $string = $string .= "<div id=\"imgInfo\" class=\"imgInfo absolute top0 right0\">";
    $string = $string .= "</div>";

    $string .= "<div class=\"imageWrapper mauto relative fadeInClass\">";

    $string .= "<img id=\"imgSrc\" src=\"assets/img/$id.png\" class=\"babeImg borb2 boxsb\">";

    //BILLEDE VALUEN
    $string .= "<input id=\"imgValue\" class=\"absolute displayn\" type=\"radio\" value=\"$id\">";

    //STAR FORM
    $string .= "<div id=\"starWrapper\" class=\"starWrapper flex center absolute left0 bot0 mar10\">";
    $string .= "<form action=\"\" method=\"post\" class=\"flex flex-drr absolute bot0 left0\">";

    for ($i = 5; $i > 0; $i--) {
        $string .= "<input id=\"vote$i\" class=\"vote displayn\" type=\"radio\" name=\"vote\" value=\"$i\">";
        $string .= "<label for=\"vote$i\"></label>";
    }

    //SUBMIT FORM
    $string .= "<input type=\"submit\" id=\"voteSubmit\" class=\"displayn\">";

    $string .= "</form>";
    $string .= "</div>"; //starWrapper
    $string .= "</div>"; //imageWrapper
    $string .= "</div>"; //innerVotingWrapper
    $string .= "</div>"; //YDRE NAV TIL AT CENTRERE
}
//COL10
$test = "<div id=\"testid\" class=\"bgw\">";
$test .= "</div>";
?>

<div class="flex">
    <div class="col10 bgc2">
        <?php echo $test; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col90 bgc1 relative vh100">
        <?php echo $string; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

newimage.php

```
<?php

require_once '../includes/db.php';
require_once '../includes/functions.php';
$dbCon = dbCon();

//$voteValue = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'voteValue', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
//$imgValue = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'imgValue', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

$voteValue = $_POST['voteValue'];
$imgValue = $_POST['imgValue'];

$ip = ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

$stmtt = $dbCon->prepare("INSERT INTO rating_users (user_ip, user_vote, user_source) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmtt->bind_param('iii', $ip, $voteValue, $imgValue);
$stmtt->execute();

//UPDATERE DATABASED
$stmt = $dbCon->prepare("UPDATE rating SET
    votes = votes + 1,
    rating = rating + ? WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('ii', $voteValue, $imgValue);
$stmt->execute();


//LAV EN SQL QUERY SOM CHECKKER AT id ikke matcher et id allerede votet af den ip
//SENDER NY QUERY AFSTED

$sql = "SELECT * FROM rating INNER JOIN rating_users ON rating_users.user_source = rating.id WHERE rating_users.user_source= $user_source AND (rating_users.user_id= $user_id OR rating_user.ip= $ip ) ";
$result = $dbCon->query($sql);
$result = $result->fetch_object();
$id = $result->id;
//HVIS DEN IKKE ER TOM SKAL DET BILLEDE + RATING DIVS SENDES SOM JSON
$imgSrc = "assets/img/" . $id . ".png";
$arr = array('imgSrc' => $imgSrc, 'id' => $id);

echo json_encode($arr);
```

Javascript/Ajax

```
var vote = document.getElementsByClassName('vote');
var voteL = vote.length;
for (let i = 0; i < voteL; i++) {
    //SKAL VÆRE LET VALUE
    let voteValue = vote[i].value;

    vote[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        var imgValue = document.getElementById("imgValue").value;
        newImage(voteValue, imgValue);
        console.log(vote[i].value);
    });
}

function newImage(voteValue, imgValue) {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "pages/newImage.php";
    var params = "voteValue=" + voteValue + "&imgValue=" + imgValue;
    http.open("POST", url, true);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http.onreadystatechange = function () { //KALDER FUNKTIONEN NÅR DNE ER KLAR
        if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {

            var Data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            console.log(this.responseText);

            var imgSrc = document.getElementById('imgSrc');
            imgSrc.src = Data.imgSrc;
            var imgValue = document.getElementById('imgValue');
            imgValue.value = Data.id;

            var ratingValue = Data.rating;
            var starWrapper = document.getElementById('starWrapper');
            //HVIS IPEN HAR STEMT PÅ BILLEDET BLIVER HANS VOTES RETURNERET TIL VISNING OG IKKE MULIGT AT STEMME
            if (Data.rating) {

                // OPRETTER VOTED/EMPTY STARS HVIS DER ER VOTET
                var string = "";
                for (i = 1; i <= ratingValue; i++) {
                    string = string + "<div class=\"voteFull\"></div>";
                }
                for (i = ratingValue; i < 5; i++) {
                    string = string + "<div class=\"voteEmpty\"></div>";
                }
                starWrapper.innerHTML = string;

            } else {
                console.log('Data.rating er ikke sat');
            }

        }
    };
    http.send(params);
}

var testId = document.getElementById('testid');
testId.addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log('Clicked');
});
```

Comment: Try and format code either with four spaces or the `{}` button which tries to do it automatically. Presentation matters.

Comment: Okay i am sorry i will do this next time

Comment: If you know the rating ID when you should be able to do `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rating_users WHERE user_ip=?` and check that they haven't voted before. Your schema seems a bit odd. Usually you have a table of things you can rate, and a table of ratings performed by users.

Comment: I'd rather use a different condition: either there are no voting records for the user, or there is and it has a number lower than the limit. My conditions would never include a `limit 1` and `order by rand()` clauses unless I explicitly wanted surprises and unpredicatbility.

Comment: I am not using a login for this... it is supposed to be ip, not my command ...

And limit 1 order by rand is because the person entering the website will get a random image from the database and limited by 1 ?

How would you do this then? :)

Answer (score 0):

Of this is a requirement of the data 1 you s should have a unique constraint on t2 on columns `user_source` since the user can only vote once, additionally you could add the `ip` to the unique constraint to limit one vote per ip/user

```
SELECT *
FROM rating
INNER JOIN rating_users 
    ON rating_users.user_source = rating.id
WHERE rating_users.user_source= $user_source
AND (rating_users.user_id= $user_id OR rating_user.ip= $ip )
```

The above query should return zero if the user or ip hasn't voted yet for the current photo

**EDIT:** I altered the query to limit to the user_id/user_ip and segment to the current photo (user_source). this means you'll have to pass the following to the query `$user_source`, `$user_id`, `$ip`

Comment: This is too good to be true :') i will take a quick bath and when i come back i will test this... if this work i will reward you!

Comment: what is the user image column? is it rating_user.user_vote or rating.category?

Comment: the id from table1 will be stored as rating_users.user_source on table 2 :)

Comment: if I'm understanding you correctly the above query should provide the desired result.

Comment: Hmm

$sql = "select count(*) from rating Inner join rating_users on     rating_users.user_source = rating.id Where rating_users.user_source = user_source or rating_users.user_ip = $ip ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$result = $dbCon->query($sql);
$result = $result->fetch_object();
$id = $result->id;
When i run the code and try to send $id back with the AJAX call that i use, the $id will return as NULL

Comment: you where should be like this `WHERE rating_users.user_source=:user_source
AND (rating_users.user_id=:user_id OR rating_user.ip=:ip)` the parenthesis are important, also remove the `count(*)` and replace with `*` I'll edit the answer

Comment: I will try give me a sec..

Could you explain what this means "=:" ?
And should i change anything? you talked about "1 you s should have a unique constraint on t2 on columns user_source" i am not sure what i have to do in this step ?

Comment: sorry in PHP it is ideal to use PDO to make a command to send parameters to mysql to avoid sql injection. if you are using concatenation you can replace it with a php variable but I would strongly recommend using PDO and a parameterized query, if you update your question to have the php code (obviously hide connection info and replace with like $dbip $username $password) and I can rewrite it using PDO

Comment: Our servers do not accept PDO, also i use prepared statements... I am a bit confused, the ajax call dont even return anything but an error now :/ is this correct? "rating_users.user_source=user_source" ?

Comment: Also this is the query now : SELECT * FROM rating INNER JOIN rating_users ON rating_users.user_source = rating.id WHERE rating_users.user_source=user_source AND (rating_users.user_id=user_id OR rating_user.ip = $ip) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1

But the ajax call does not return anything but an error

Comment: ok the if you're using a prepared statement that is fine, my apologies. in PDO `:` denotes a parameter being passed I'll change the `:` to a `$` but I'm not sure they will match your php variable names

Comment: Okay i see, but where would you get these variables from? user_id in the db is just an auto increment value.

Please take a look here : http://xch07.wi2.sde.dk/sandbox/rating8/index.php

This is the site.. :)

Comment: is it possible to show the result from running the following in mysql `show create table rating` and `show create table rating_users`? and also show some of your php code just the query and what you're returning?

Comment: Sure i have edited my answer so my php/javascript code is now included

Table
Create Table
rating
CREATE TABLE `rating` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AU...

Table
Create Table
rating_users
CREATE TABLE `rating_users` (
 `user_id` int(11) ...